# multi-auth with tipfy on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, tipfy

I'm working with the tipfy framework (tipfy.org) on app engine and am having some real problems. I've been trying to get an extention "auth-extention" to work all night. It allows users to sign in via facebook/twitter/openid etc..

The extention can be found at the link below,  the code looks like pretty straight forward if your python ninja, but I'm new to all this and frankly its baffaling!

I've spent the last 24hours try to work it out, but I keep getting errors. 
There seems to be around 1k downloads of the mod I'm trying to integrate and not many complaints so It must be something simple I'm doing wrong.

Heres a link to the multi auth plugin:
http://tipfy-auth.appspot.com/
http://code.google.com/p/tipfy-ext-auth/source/browse/#hg/examples/multi-auth

All I need is the login system above integrated, which according to the tipfy docs should be pretty straight forward, but for some reason.. it's bundled in a way that isn't straight out of the box use.

What I was really getting at was.. to ask if anyone could attach a working app with the login system above (the actual source of it seems to be provided) so I can try and understand where I've gone wrong.. it would be greatly appreciated andI'd be happy to send you a small reward.

Comment: A better title for your question would help you get answers faster.  The tags are enough to indicate to others that it involves app-engine.

Comment: Appologies, I was not 100% sure what to call it as I didn't think too many people would know of tipfy specifically. But if people have had app engine experience this should be a walk in the park really, just installing an extention. Cheers

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Can you show some code that's producing errors?

Comment: @Wooble isn't 1 hour too short a time to close a question. We could wait for some clarification from the poster.

Comment: @Wooble, sorry for taking so long to reply. It's a missing modual error, but when I think I've fixed that the actual file goes astray and the url defined in url.py, you have no idea how much stress this has caused me, do you mind if I post this again? And perhaps advise a more suitable title Thanks.

Comment: I too tried this tipfy usecase and gave up in favor of federated login + JQuery and the facebook connect solution here http://riccomini.name/Topics/Web/GoogleAppEngine/FacebookConnect/

Comment: @user547107 have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761140/tipfy-notfound-404-when-accessing-multi-auth-example-locally/4910704#4910704) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851536/authentication-using-any-openid-with-tipfy/4851820#4851820)