# Tipfy: "NotFound: 404" when accessing multi-auth example locally

Tags: google-app-engine, tipfy

I am using the Tipfy framework ( tipfy.org ) on the Google App Engine. I would like to extend the multi-auth example ( http://tipfy-auth.appspot.com/ ).
To try the example, I installed Tipfy.
 The *hello_world* app is accessible through the browser if I run the local server.
Then I added the multi-auth app in a second directory called multi_auth, added it in the config.py *apps_installed* list (removed hello_world) and reloaded the page.

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

*
  File "/home/ideaglobe/ideabox/tipfy/project/multiauthapp/distlib/tipfy/__init__.py", line 442, in wsgi_app

   [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] response = self.handle_exception(request, e)

*
  File "/home/ideaglobe/ideabox/tipfy/project/multiauthapp/distlib/tipfy/__init__.py", line 430, in wsgi_app

   [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] rv = self.dispatch(request)

*
  File "/home/ideaglobe/ideabox/tipfy/project/multiauthapp/distlib/tipfy/__init__.py", line 547, in dispatch

   [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] raise request.routing_exception

  [console ready]
  >>> dump()
  Local variables in frame
  self  <tipfy.Tipfy object at 0x9d7f22c>
  request   <Request 'http://localhost:8080/' [GET]>
  >>>

NotFound: 404: Not Found
```

Obviously, the handler is not found, but why? Where can I set which app should be loaded?

I would be glad about a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I just did the same process last night succesfully:

1. Be sure to have downloaded all the extensions needed by the example using `buildout`
2. Copy the multi-auth `config.py` file to the app root overwriting the original one.
3. Copy all the files from multi-auth `static` and `templates` folders to the app root `static` and `templates` folders
4. Be sure that config.py has `'apps.multi-auth'` in the `apps_installed` list

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the rules for the request handlers as described in the documentation?

http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/extensions/auth/#authentication-endpoints

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. The rules are defined. For instance *Rule('/', endpoint='home', handler='handlers.HomeHandler')*

Comment: can you share more of your source code? maybe in a public repository or a gist?

Comment: Of course. This points to the example's source code: http://code.google.com/p/ideabox-test/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fproject%2Fmultiauthapp